# When I want to reload synaptic package manager, I get an error

Tags: apt, synaptic

When i click `reload` after few minutes I get this error :

```
W: Failed to fetch       
gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ir.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_natty_
universe_binary-i386_Packages  
Hash Sum mismatch, E:Some index files failed to download. 
They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you have a slow or a mirror that is not fully up-to-date.

Suggest use Software Sources and change your mirror - i.e. Choose Other from Download from and change to another mirror source.

Finally re-run update-manager and check for new updates.

[image]